# How to get the current time in Solidity

Tags: solidity, timestamp

How can I get the current time in Solidity. I don't need the current block's time given by `now` and `block.timestamp`, but rather the actual current time.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: you mean, current System time?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Within the Ethereum Virtual Machine, there isn't a way to get the current time, other than the block time. So there is no way to get it in Solidity.

**Why?**

There is disagreement between computers about what the current time is, and Ethereum needs to run every transaction with exactly the same outcome on every node.

**What next?**

Outline what you're trying to accomplish and ask about that.

- Are you trying to time how long a transaction takes? Run the node locally and time it
- Are you trying to achieve sub-block precision of payments? Payment channels might be what you're looking for
- Trying to display a verified time in a Dapp? Use the local time, bounded by block timestamp
- etc. etc.